# Changing LoginUI

Tags: c#, windows-authentication

I am working on project that requires me changing log in a windows pc through face recognition from password matching that we see everyday. But I having problem starting my program with loginUI. Can anyone suggest me any way about how I can fix this. I am coding this project in C#. Please help......
If anyone can provide any web link as tutorial about taking inputs from loginUI, that would be a great help.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand correctly, but if you want your own application to replace the windows login, you have to change the Windows Shell. Google help you find more specific information on that.

Comment: @Mathieu    <br/> Thank you sir for your reply. <br/>This is exactly what I was trying to do. But problem is I could not find any appropriate tutorial on that. So if you can suggest some tutorial sites that would be a great help.<br/> Thank you again.

Comment: Technically, you're not replacing the Windows shell. The Windows shell is Windows Explorer, which doesn't get invoked until *after* you've logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tutorial with a couple of techniques to accomplish what you want.

http://windows7themes.net/how-to-replace-explorer-exe-in-windows-7.html

Note that this will overwrite the desktop GUI loading. I'm not sure if you can then manually load `explorer.exe` as the shell to continue normally to the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a custom credential provider: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx